# Use tenet/data parameter in Ramda pipe again

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to do something like this -

```
const getData = (req, ctx) => (accounts) => R.compose
    ( R.andThen((result) => {
        result.map( item => {
            const xx = [...new Set(accounts.filter(x => x.id=== item.id).map(item => item.prop2))]; // need to use accounts variable i.e. the data parameter.
        ... do some code here based on xx          
        return result;
    })
    , callSomeApi(req, ctx)
    , R.map(R.prop('id'))
);

let accounts  = [ {id: '123", ....} , .... ]; // aaray of some data with property id 
const testData= await getData(req,ctx) (accounts);
```

As per the above program, I will be passing accounts array to func getData and this param would act as data/tenet to Ramda func. I need to access this variable later also in pipe func when api returns the result. But the above syntax doesn't work and fails on first step itself i.e. - *R.map(R.prop('id'))*

What is the correct way to achieve this? I know one possible way is to create a separate func for filtering after receiving response but I want to understand if this is achievable in the single pipe func ?

Answer (score 0):

I feel as though you're trying to squeeze something where it doesn't belong.  Ramda certainly has some techniques to help make point-free code.  But if the work doesn't fall into the sweet spot of a composition pipeline, then it's probably better not to try to force it.

I'm sure this isn't an exact match for what you want to do, but the above code looks to me as though it can be written with something like

```js
const getData = (req, ctx) => (accounts) =>
  callSomeApi (req, ctx) (pluck ('id') (accounts)) 
    .then (map (item => pluck ('prop2') (uniq (filter (propEq ('id') (item)) (accounts)))))
```

Here we use a number of Ramda helpers, but we don't try to organize the whole thing into a pipeline, and I believe that simplifies things.  (Even if I'm missing something (what else is supposed to happen with `xx`?), I think it's a simple enough structure to build on.